# A lower-bound on matrix-function with vector product

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory, lower-bounds

I am currently trying to show that a sequence of homeomorphisms converges to some limiting homeomorphism using Anderson's the [inductive convergence criterion](http://www.numdam.org/article/CM_1987__63_2_159_0.pdf).  However I can't explicitly compute the following necessary bound.

---

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$-skew-symmetric matrix, $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $M,\epsilon>0$.  Define the bump function $\phi(z):= |z-1| |z+1| I_{|z|\leq 1}$.  What is the following quantity equal to (or upper-bounded by):
$$
\alpha(A,c,M,\epsilon):=\inf_{\|x\|,\|y\|\leq M,\|x-y\|>\epsilon} \left\|
e^{A\phi(\|x-c\|)}(x-c) - 
e^{A\phi(\|y-c\|)}(y-c)
\right\|.
$$

All, I know, for-sure so far is that this quantity is positive.